# Power series for $(A+\epsilon I)^{-1}$ for large $\epsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series, inverse, matrix-calculus

I am trying to figure out a power series for $(A+\epsilon I)^{-1}$ when $A$ is an invertible matrix and $\epsilon$ is large. The Neumann series can be used when $\epsilon$ is small. Is there something similar for large $\epsilon$?

I am thinking I can use Woodbury matrix identity to convert $(A+\epsilon I)^{-1}$ into a form that requires an inversion of $(I+\epsilon A^{-1})$ instead in which case we can apply the Neumann series. Would this be the best way to do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not write this as $\epsilon^{-1} (I + \epsilon^{-1} A)^{-1}$?

Comment: You need not to assume that $A$ is invertible. If $H$ is any square matrix with spectral radius < 1, then $I+H$ is invertible, and $$(I+H)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-H)^n.$$